# Apps Script - understand if a cell is filled with a certain color

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet with cells filled with different colors. I want to get the cells that are filled as red. How can I get this?

When I search for it I only get explanations of how to fill a cell, which is not what I want.

Any tip/clue is more than welcome!

Comment: `I want to get the cells` is not descriptive enough. You want to get the values? the references of the cells ? Also you need to provide some efforts. If you google search `get background color google apps script` the first thread is about [getBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) . This function can give you the background of a particular range of cells. Do some research and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66651805/11225291) to show your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Apps Script method [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) will return a range array containing the hex values of the background color of each cell.

Then, once you have this 2D array of your range background colors you can simply iterate over it by row and column to check which one match your desired color and print their corresponding row and column values.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  // Get your desired range (2D array)
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:L20');
  
  // Get the array of background color in each cell for that range
  var bkg = range.getBackgrounds();

  // iterate over rows 
  for(var i=0;i<bkg.length;i++){
    // iterate over columns
    for(var j=0;j<bkg[i].length;j++){
    // if the specific cell at row i and column j is red
      if(bkg[i][j]==='#ff0000'){
        // log row and column starting by 1
        Logger.log('row :'+(i+1))
        Logger.log('column :'+(j+1))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Mateo, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi ! If my answer solved you question please consider accepting (the tick mark on the left of my answer) and/or upvoting my answer. Thanks !